# Solr Stats Facet "invalid number"

Tags: solr, statistics, components

Hi and Thanks in advance.
Actually i'm using solr 4.10 and having an issue with stats facet behaviour
i'm trying to perform a query where stats.field=X&Stats.facet=Y
Both fields X and Y are defined as **TrieIntField** fields, Field X is **Mutlivalue** and Field Y is singleValue.
I get this Error

**error":{"msg":"Invalid Number: `\b$\n)S","code":400}}**, i'm sure all values are Int , no strings ! 
Any ideas ?

Comment: show your query and all logs with error